# Cannot run react template i downloaded

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-scripts

i have downloaded a react template and wanted to customize it. i have put the node modules folder and when i run the npm run start command i get the following errors

npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\hp\Desktop\ReactIntroduction\material-kit-react-main\pack
age.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent Could not read package.json: Error: ENOENT: no such file or dire
ctory, open 'C:\Users\hp\Desktop\ReactIntroduction\material-kit-react-main\packa
ge.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

Comment: Seems like you might be missing the package.json file which is where the command of "start" would have been defined. You also might not have run the command in the correct directory, make sure you are in the root directory of the project.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks there no such file named 'package.json' in the folder 'material-kit-react-main'.
I'm assuming you where download the file from https://github.com/creativetimofficial/material-kit-react.git, you will got a zip file named 'material-kit-react-main.zip'.

1. unpack the archive file, you will got a folder named 'material-kit-react-main'.
2. enter the folder named 'material-kit-react-main', you will see there many files, including 'package.json'.
3. run 'npm install' command to install dependencies.
4. run 'npm start' command to start the project.